# como esconder uma progressBar apos determinado tempo

Tags: android, thread, progress-bar

Estou usando o seguinte código

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (cont < 100) {
                cont += 1;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }).start();
```

O problema é que na hora de setar a Visibility aparece o seguinte erro

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1087                                                                           Process: br.alphatec.ms_cliente_alpha1, PID: 23000                                                                           android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

E quando o código estava assim executava, porem muito rápido, e se eu aumentar o valor(100) que esta no while ele para de funcionar

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (cont < 100) {

               cont += 1;           
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Achei estranho a segunda solução funcionar, porque ainda sim está violando a restrição de single threading do framework.

O mais certo seria o primeiro caso pois não está fazendo uma espera ocupada.

Voltando ao problema, você não pode modificar `Views` estando em uma `Thread` separada da `Main Thread`.

Para resolver o problema você precisa continuar o processamento na `Main Thread` após a espera na `Thread` separada.

O primeiro exemplo ficaria:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (cont < 100) {
            cont += 1;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        progressBar.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

---

Para coisas um pouco mais avançadas, recomendo que dê uma olhada no conceito de `AsyncTask`.

Usando `AsyncTask` seu exemplo ficaria:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override protected Long doInBackground(Void... args) {
        while (cont < 100) {
            cont += 1;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

No `AsyncTask` o método `doInBackground` é chamado num `ThreadPoolExecutor` e o método `onPostExecute` na `Main Thread`.

Existem outras funcionalidades no `AsyncTask`, mas não é o escopo da pergunta.